# Why does "Hominem unius libri timeo" use comparativus unius instead of positivus unum?

Tags: accusative, comparative, aquinas

Why does "Hominem unius libri timeo" use comparativus *unius* instead of positivus *unum*? Does it mean "I fear a man of one book (more)"? Or does that *unius* belong to *hominem* because it is accusativus+comparativus?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It looks like a comparative (cf. *facilius, melius,* and many others) but it is in fact a genitive.
Thus *unius libri* is "of one book".

The word *unus* has an unusual declension:

- nom: *unus, una, unum*
- acc: *unum, unam, unum*
- gen: *unius*
- dat: *uni*
- abl: *uno, una, uno*

The same genitive in *-ius* is used by a couple of pronouns.

There is no comparative form of *unus* in Latin, nor do I know what "onner" should mean.

Comment: Ah ok looks like the online dictionary is wrong, I checked somewhere else, most probably they generated the declinations. thanks!

Comment: just to add the other eight that share the same irregularity:  alius, alter, ullus, nullus, uter, neuter, solus, totus.

Comment: @oguzalb I recommend Wiktionary ([gets it right](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/unus)) or [Collatinus](https://outils.biblissima.fr/en/collatinus-web/) (also gets it right but cannot be linked). Note that the pronunciation is different, by the way: the comparative has a short i and is stressed on the third to last syllable.

Comment: @d_e: In addition, is, ille, iste, hic, and qui also have genitives on -ius.